# Samsung accessory SDK 2.3.2 - Device unreachable

Tags: android, samsung-galaxy-gear

I've built an app based on the sample Native Hello Accessory (Android - Provider, Tizen - Consumer). Both apps work great when I install them and I can connect both devices and exchange data.

The problem is in the Android app. When I shut down the smartphone and turn it back on and launch the developed app, I can´t connect with the Tizen Consumer app. I get the following error message:

> device not reachable

Comment: Solved it, worked with multiaccessory sample, it was not difficult to adapt the code from that sample.